# product of square of two independent variables

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable, independence

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent,

- can we assume $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent in general?
- can we assume $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent if  $X$ and $Y$ are *also* identically distributed (in addition to being independent)?
- can we assume $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent if both $X$ and $Y$ (which are assumed independent) followed the normal distribution (not necessarily identically distributed)?
- can we assume $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent if both $X$ and $Y$ followed the normal distribution with identical mean and variance (in addition to being independent)?

Answer (score 4):

In general, $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent if $X$ and $Y$ are independent for any measurable functions $f,g$. Since $f(X) = X^2$ and $g(Y) = Y^2$ are measurable, the squares are independent (if $X$ and $Y$ were independent).